# Wait until a block reaches its completion block

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

I want to wait for an async task to finish (getting reverse geocoding result), so I'm using blocks like follows:
The method will be executed `[self.dataArray count]` times:

```
    for (Trip_ObjC *trip in self.dataArray) {

            NSData *tripData = [trip.coordinates dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSArray *coordinatesArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:tripData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

            [self prepareDistanceAndTimeArray:trip andCoordinates:coordinatesArray];
            [self prepareMapRoutes:trip andCoordinates:coordinatesArray];
            [self prepareDates:trip];

//HERE IS THE TARGETTED METHOD
            NSLog(@"entered");
            [self getAddressFromTrip:trip andCoordinates:coordinatesArray completionHandler:^{
                NSLog(@"GOT ADDRESS");
            }];
        }
```

Then this is the declaration of `getAddressFromTrip`

```
-(void)getAddressFromTrip:(Trip_ObjC*)trip andCoordinates:(NSArray*)tripArray completionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler{
    NSLog(@"getAddressFromTrip with ID %d",trip.id_);

    //Got userLocationBegin
   // GOT userLocationEnd


    [self geocodeLocation:userLocationBegin andUserLocationEnd:userLocationEnd andTripId:trip.id_ completionHandler:^{
        if (completionHandler) {
            NSLog(@"completionHandler");
            completionHandler();
        }
    }];
}
```

Now here is the problem, it does not simply enter the `reverseGeocodeCoordinate` block and execute the code, I just have the last loop result:

```
 -(void)geocodeLocation:(CLLocation*)userLocationBegin andUserLocationEnd:(CLLocation*)userLocationEnd andTripId:(int)tripId completionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler {
        NSLog(@"geocodeLocation with ID %d",tripId);
        CLLocationCoordinate2D c2dBegin=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(userLocationBegin.coordinate.latitude, userLocationBegin.coordinate.longitude);

        __block NSString *addressBegin;

        NSLog(@"Before entrering geocoding block");
        [[LMGeocoder sharedInstance] reverseGeocodeCoordinate:c2dBegin
                                                      service:kLMGeocoderGoogleService
                                            completionHandler:^(LMAddress *address, NSError *error) {

                                                if (address && !error) {

                                                    NSLog(@"trip.id_ %d",tripId);
                                                    addressBegin=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ,%@",address.administrativeArea,address.locality];

if(completionHandler){
                                                    completionHandler();
                                                }
                                                }
                                                else {
                                                    NSLog(@"Error reverse: %@", error.description);
                                                }
                                            }];
    }
```

LOG:

```
2014-12-04 16:51:09.435 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] entered
2014-12-04 16:51:09.436 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] getAddressFromTrip with ID 11
2014-12-04 16:51:09.436 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] geocodeLocation with ID 11
2014-12-04 16:51:09.436 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] Before entrering geocoding block
2014-12-04 16:51:09.436 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] entered
2014-12-04 16:51:09.436 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] getAddressFromTrip with ID 13
2014-12-04 16:51:09.436 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] geocodeLocation with ID 13
2014-12-04 16:51:09.437 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] Before entrering geocoding block
2014-12-04 16:51:09.437 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] entered
2014-12-04 16:51:09.437 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] getAddressFromTrip with ID 14
2014-12-04 16:51:09.437 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] geocodeLocation with ID 14
2014-12-04 16:51:09.438 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] Before entrering geocoding block
2014-12-04 16:51:09.438 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] entered
2014-12-04 16:51:09.438 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] getAddressFromTrip with ID 9
2014-12-04 16:51:09.438 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] geocodeLocation with ID 9
2014-12-04 16:51:09.438 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] Before entrering geocoding block
2014-12-04 16:51:09.438 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] entered
2014-12-04 16:51:09.439 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] getAddressFromTrip with ID 1
2014-12-04 16:51:09.439 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] geocodeLocation with ID 1
2014-12-04 16:51:09.439 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] Before entrering geocoding block
2014-12-04 16:51:09.536 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] trip.id_ 1
2014-12-04 16:51:09.852 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] addressBegin
2014-12-04 16:51:09.852 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] addressEnd
2014-12-04 16:51:09.852 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] completionHandler
2014-12-04 16:51:09.852 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] GOT ADDRESS
2014-12-04 16:51:09.862 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] addressBegin
2014-12-04 16:51:09.862 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] addressEnd
2014-12-04 16:51:09.862 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] completionHandler
2014-12-04 16:51:09.862 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] GOT ADDRESS
2014-12-04 16:51:09.880 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] addressBegin
2014-12-04 16:51:09.880 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] addressEnd
2014-12-04 16:51:09.880 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] completionHandler
2014-12-04 16:51:09.881 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] GOT ADDRESS
2014-12-04 16:51:09.894 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] addressBegin
2014-12-04 16:51:09.895 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] addressEnd
2014-12-04 16:51:09.895 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] completionHandler
2014-12-04 16:51:09.895 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] GOT ADDRESS
2014-12-04 16:51:10.023 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] addressBegin
2014-12-04 16:51:10.023 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] addressEnd
2014-12-04 16:51:10.023 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] completionHandler
2014-12-04 16:51:10.023 GOTTIZ[18710:2151731] GOT ADDRESS
```

You can notice that it does not enter the `reverseGeocodeCoordinate` block and continues looping until the the last element and display it . And that `trip.id_` is only displayed once .
I don't know how it actually continue looping even that it does not receive the completionHandler().

Comment: just wanted to note that if you make that many requests at once, Google will block you pretty fast.

Comment: @simpleBob: So, what is the best approach to reverse geocode ? Thank you .

Comment: use caching, save all requests already made, and try to send as few requests as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code for [LMGeocoder](https://github.com/lminhtm/LMGeocoder/tree/master/LMGeocoder), it's definitely designed to be used for one request at a time, given it uses a singleton pattern that keeps state:

```
@interface LMGeocoder ()
{
    NSMutableData *receivedData;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D requestedCoordinate;
    NSString *requestedAddress;
    LMGeocodeCallback completionHandler;
    LMGeocoderService currentService;
    BOOL isReverseGeocoding;
}
@end
```

Therefore you cannot loop through the requests as you are doing, but instead you will need to *chain* the events; starting the next query only after the previous one has completed.

This is outside of limitations imposed by the Google code that `LMGeocoder` wraps (I didn't look at the Google code).

**EDIT** This is an example of what I mean by chaining the requests:

1. Add an instance variable that holds the current index into `self.dataArray` in the class implementation file:

   ```
   @interface YourClass () {
       NSUInteger _dataArrayIndex;
   }
   - (void)_nextRequest;
   @end
   ```
2. Add a method that performs the *next* request.  This must be called to start the whole request chain, after first ensuring that `_dataArrayIndex` is reset to `0`:

   ```
   - (void)_nextRequest
   {
       if (_dataArrayIndex >= [self.dataArray count])
           return;
       Trip_ObjC *trip = self.dataArray[_dataArrayIndex++];
       NSData *tripData = [trip.coordinates dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       NSArray *coordinatesArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:tripData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

       [self prepareDistanceAndTimeArray:trip andCoordinates:coordinatesArray];
       [self prepareMapRoutes:trip andCoordinates:coordinatesArray];
       [self prepareDates:trip];

       NSLog(@"entered");
       [self getAddressFromTrip:trip andCoordinates:coordinatesArray completionHandler:^{
           NSLog(@"GOT ADDRESS");
       }];
   }
   ```
3. And finally in the completion handler, call `_nextRequest` to process the next request.  This is the chain.

Comment: Oh yes! You have reason ! But do you have any idea of the best approach to geocode ? I'm afraid that if I make a lot of requests (to Google or also Apple reverse geocoding service) they'll block me.

Comment: @androniennn I've no idea about being blocked by Google/Apple and that's outside the scope of the question. As mentioned in my answer, you need to chain the requests, so 1) keep the current index into the array in an instance variable. 2) put the code from inside that loop into a method, which fires the request as it currently does. 3) call that method from the completion handler.

Comment: @androniennn: Apple won't block you; Google's API will limit you, although you can apply for a limit increase.

Comment: @Droppy I'm not honestly understanding what you mean. Can you please try to describe what you wrote with code? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Droppy, no hints please ?